# positions groups of nodes to each other in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, grouping

I would like to position nodes in groups a and b in the following way:
[image]

Group b of tikz nodes is positioned in some symmetric way relative to group a.

The following script creates nodes corresponding to group a:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a1)[text width=0.75\linewidth, text height=2cm, draw] {
  };
  \node(a2)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw] at (a1.east)[anchor=west]{
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to group them and  add group b?

**Update**

I am checking the answer from @Torbjorn

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
  mymat/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    % style of matrix border                                                                                                                  
    draw=black!20,
    dashed,
    % distance between columns in matrix                                                                                                      
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={ % set style for nodes inside matrix                                                                                               
      draw=red,
      solid
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [mymat, name=m1] {
    % the |[..]| at the start of a cell lets you set the style for an individual cell                                                         
    |[minimum width=0.75\textwidth]| node a1
    & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\ };
  \matrix [mymat, below=2mm of m1, name=m2]  {   |[minimum width=0.33\textwidth]| node b1 &    |[minimum width=0.33\textwidth]| node b2 &    \
|[minimum width=0.33\textwidth]| node b3 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

But I would like node a1 centred with regard to node a2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For groups of nodes like that, might make sense to use a `\matrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
  mymat/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    % style of matrix itself (outer  border, background)
    draw=black!50,
    fill=blue!10,
    dashed,
    % distance between columns in matrix
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={ % set style for nodes inside matrix
       draw=red,
       solid,
       anchor=center 
   }
  } 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [mymat, name=m1] {
    |[minimum width=0.75\textwidth]| node a1
    & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\ };

  \matrix [mymat,
           below=2mm of m1,
           nodes={minimum width=0.3\textwidth}, % set common width
           name=m2]  { 
   node b1 &    
  |[minimum height=3cm]| node b2 &   
  node b3 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. "node a1" and "node a2" are merely labels for nodes which will be filled with text and pictures.

Comment: @Viesturs I don't get it, can't you replace `node a1` etc. with the text/images you want?

Comment: @Viesturs The way I read your question my code does *exactly* what you ask for, so you need to help me understand what you want.

Comment: In your example, how can I make a1.east correspond to a2.west, where a1 and a2 are cells in the matrix?

Comment: @Viesturs `column sep=-\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Where do I insert `column sep=-\pgflinewidth`?

Comment: @Viesturs In my original code I had `column sep=2mm`, replace the `2mm` with `-\pgflinewidth`. But I already [edited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/429662/revisions).

Comment: using `column sep=-\pgflinewidth` doesn't seem to work - see the update to my question.

Comment: @Viesturs Add `anchor=center` to the `nodes` key in the `mymat` style, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

with use of `tikz` libraries `backgrounds`, `\fit` and `positioning` is simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0.05\linewidth, 
    box/.style args = {#1/#2}{
            draw=red, draw=red, minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2},
    box/.default = 0.3\linewidth/0.3\linewidth
                        ]
\node (a1) [box=0.75\linewidth/0.2\linewidth] {node a1};
\node (a2) [box=0.2\linewidth/0.3\linewidth,
            right=of a1] {node a2};
\scoped[on background layer] 
    \node[draw=gray!25, very thick, dotted, fill=gray!50, 
          fit=(a1) (a2)] {};
%
\node (b1) [box,below right=12mm and 0mm of a1.south west] {node a1};
\node (b2) [box,right=of b1] {node b2};
\node (b3) [box,right=of b2] {node b3};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[draw=gray!25, very thick, dotted, fill=gray!50,
          fit=(b1) (b3)] {};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is group b?

Comment: @Viesturs, added now ...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a1)[text width=0.6\linewidth, text height=2cm, draw] {
  };
  \node(a2)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw,
  right=of a1] {};
  \node(b3)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw,below=1.5cm of a2] {
  };
  \node(b2)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw,left=of b3] {
  };
  \node(b1)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw,left=of b2] {
  };
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \node[fit=(a1) (a2),inner sep=3mm,fill=gray!20] (f1){};
 \node[fit=(b1) (b2) (b3),inner sep=3mm,fill=gray!20] (f2){};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to centre node b3 below a2.

Comment: @Viesturs Of course, you are the boss ;-) Please feel free to move it wherever you want it to be.

Comment: How can I do it? I modify your code and b3 is always centred below a2.

Comment: @Viesturs   Just say ` \node(b3)[text width=0.25\textwidth, text height=3cm, draw] at (4,-3) {
  };` and then adjust the coordinates `(4,-3)`.

Comment: I would replace `(4, -3)` with `at (a2.south east)[anchor=north east]`

Comment: @Viesturs Sure, as I said, you are the boss. My answer was really on relative placement of the a and b chains and more importantly on making the a and b nodes "groups" by using fit, and also to shade the background.

Comment: The trick of this question is to position node `f2` at `(f1.south)[anchor=north]`.  That would make the answer!

Comment: @Viesturs I draw the fit nodes only after the other nodes. So one really has to position a b node first. But if I understand you correctly now, then I believe that Torbjørn T.'s answer is the best one,